# Classic ASP - format date

Tags: asp-classic

I have a date being extracted from the database which is formatted as following

```
12/23/2005
```

Which is

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

I want to convert it in classic asp to the following

```
December 23 2004
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Cheers,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Function FormatDate(input)
    FormatDate = MonthName(Month(CDate(input))) & " " & Day(CDate(input)) & " " & Year(CDate(input))
End Function
Response.Write(FormatDate("12/23/2005"))
```

I'm assuming you want it to show "December 23 2005" if you want it to show "December 23 2004" then just subtract one from the Year() call:

```
FormatDate = MonthName(Month(CDate(input))) & " " & Day(CDate(input)) & " " & (Year(CDate(input))-1)
```

Answer (score -3):

assuming you are doing this in c#

```
DateTime thisDate = new DateTime.Now;
String outString = thisDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Comment: C# would be for asp.net, not asp-classic